# Can I pass data through two different django projects?

Tags: python, django, project, otree

After an otree survey, I start with subprocess another django app, specially a django-oscar shop. It runs on another port.
Now, I want to pass some data from the survey (first app, otree) to the shop (second app, django-oscar).

I tried this in app2/views.py:

```
from survey.models import Player

class CatalogueView(TemplateView):
    """
    Browse all products in the catalogue
    """
    model = Player
    context_object_name = "products"
    template_name = 'catalogue/browse.html'
```

But I just get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'otree'

I also tried to import `otree.api` and I put `otree` to `installed_apps`.

Any ideas, how to handle this?

Comment: Have you looked into redis?

Comment: I just know redis from heroku from my other otree experiments, but now I am working/testing locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this a little differently.
I have waived the sub processes and have created an API with django REST framework instead. Passing parameters back and forth were imho the best approach.